# Python Flask update render_template

Tags: python, web, flask, memcached, refresh

I us memcached from python to stock two datas (state)
I use flask to create a webserver quickly. My goal is to recover these data with memcached and update to my flask template

```
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=0)
app = Flask(__name__)

def updateH():
    state = mc.get("wc_h")
    if state:
        return "yes.png"
    else:
        return "no.png"

def updateF():
    state = mc.get("wc_f")
    if state:
        return "yes.png"
    else:
        return "no.png"

@app.route('/')
def index():    
    return render_template('index.html', hstate = updateH(), fstate = updateF())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
app = Flask(__name__)
```

This work perfectly but I'm forced to reaload the page to update visual data.. (img src in my case)
Sorry for my english. Thx

Comment: I think you would need to implement a WebSocket, this might be helpful http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent

Comment: I'll try now, it seems nice to solve my problem :)